# Object reference not set to an instance of an object - accessing object from another method

Tags: c#

I'm having issues accessing an object created in a different method.

```
internal class Connect
{
    private ServerSession session;
    private ClientProperties properties;

    public void initialize()
    {

        this.properties = new ClientProperties("PropertyA", "PropertyB");

        // the code for ServerSession() resides in a separate class file
        session = new ServerSession(properties);

        // this is a pseudo event handler...I have real eventhandlers in my application (I just can't share due to NDA)
        session.eventHandler_1(new EventHanlder<Method>(this.method_1));
    }

    public void disconnect()
    {
        session.Disconnect();
    }

    public void connect(string server)
    {
        session.Connect(server, 1234);
    }
}
```

This application is used to connect to a network. I need to have the `initialize` function to initialize the network protocol (this method is accessed in the `Program.cs` file when the application is first initialized).

The issue I'm having is I'm getting an `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` error when accessing the `connect()` method from my application WinForm.

Excerpt of `form.cs`

```
namespace MyApplication
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        Connect server = new Connect();

        // this method is called when I establish a connection to the network
        private void connectServer()
        {
            server("123.456.789");
        }
    }
}
```

How do I properly access the `connect()` method without it throwing this error. I know it is because the object is empty for some reason, but I don't understand why since it was initialized in the same class.

Comment: Your example isn't actually calling `initialize`. Add it to your constructor or separate out the `session.Connect()` call into its own method and `initialize` before creating the connection.

Answer (score 1):

Your `initialize` method of your `Connect` class is never called, so the object’s `session` object never gets initialized. To fix that, you should call the method first.

Alternatively, move your initialization code to the constructor:

```
internal class Connect
{
    private ServerSession session;

    public Connect ()
    {
        session = new ServerSession();
        // stuff
    }

    // …
}
```

As you mentioned in the comments, you set up an instance of `Connect` somewhere else when the application starts, and then expect it to appear in your form. However, that is not how objects work. When doing `new Connect()` you are creating a *new* object—that’s the whole point of it. If you don’t want to create a new object, then don’t create a new one, but reuse the one you already created.

There are multiple ways to do that. The cleanest way would be to use to pass the existing instance to your `MainForm`. For example through the constructor of the form, or by defining a property which you set:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public Connect Server
    { get; set; }

    private void connectServer()
    {
        Server.connect("123.456.789");
    }
}
```

And then in your `Main`, you can do something like this:

```
Connect connect = new Connect();

MainForm form = new MainForm();
form.Server = connect;
form.Show();
```

Comment: The `initialize` is indeed being initialized in the `Program.cs` in the `static void Main()` method.

Comment: Well, then you are initializing *some* `Connect` object. But your `MainForm` class creates a new one, so *that* one won’t be initialized.

Comment: Is there a way to override it so the `MainForm` doesn't overlap and create a new instance?

Answer (score 1):

As poke mentioned, make sure you call your `initialize` method first. You also need to make sure you call your `connect` method. So something like this:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    Connect server = new Connect();
    server.initialize(); // call your initialize method

    private void connectServer()
    {
        server.connect("123.456.789"); // call the connect method here
    }
}
```

Comment: I did consider this, however, I forgot to include that there is an argument variable when the `new ServerSession()` is called. I updated my post to reflect this.

Comment: @Spencer It shouldn't matter whether `new ServerSession()` has an argument variable. The point is that your `initialize` method is responsible for initializing/creating instances of the properties in your `Connect` class, and thus you need to call it before doing anything else. If you don't want to explicitly call `initialize`, then move it into the constructor as @poke mentioned.

Comment: I understand that; however, I am already calling the `initialize` method in the `Program.cs` file...so theoretically speaking, it is initialized when the program starts. Unfortunately, it's still returning null.

Comment: @Spencer You are initializing it in `Program.cs`, which is a seperate class from your `MainForm` class. Your initialized `Connect` class only resides in `Program.cs` and not `MainForm`, but `MainForm` needs an initialized `Connect` to call the `connect` method (either by creating its own or obtaining it from `Program.cs`). The simplest solution is therefore to create and initialize `Connect` in your `MainForm` class.

Comment: I tried your suggestion of moving the `initialize` method into my MainForm, but oddly it still returns the same error...the connect method is still null for some reason.

Comment: @Spencer did you call `server.connect("123.456.789")` instead of `server("123.456.789")`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49282/discussion-between-jw-lim-and-spencer)